# LaunchingAndroid application from Android browser / Chrome - phonegap

Tags: java, android, iphone, html, cordova

I'm working on a project and I want to implement qr-code scanner in it.

I tried to look for an in-app solution but i didn't find anything relevant so i decided to use a common bar-code scanner to launch an url.

When the user tries to open this link, I want Android to show him a chooser dialog where he can choose to open that link using my application.

I saw a lot of answer to a question like this, but i didn't find anyting about implementing this thing in a no-native android application.

The application is made in html5+javascript+php and all the answers i found spoke abount intent and so on...there is a way to implement the same feature using html5?

Thank you,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

here is the perfect link -
http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/

Even I am new to cordova and found many difficulties while designing my 1st plugin.

and be careful cordova 3.0 and later  version of cordova has huge difference with the earlier version.
best

Comment: Please leave a precis of the contents of the linked page as it may not be available in the future